# Problema al Filtrar array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

tengo un poco de colapso mental, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a desbloquear.

He testeado todo ya y no se por que no filtra el elemento:

```
        const nuevasNotas = appState.notas.map(element => {
            if (element[0] === nota.data.split('T')[0]) {
                console.log('hay match!');
                element[1] = element[1].filter(cosa => cosa.data !== nota.data);
                console.log('log -> ', element[1].filter(cosa => cosa.data !== nota.data));                
            }
            console.log('>>>><<<<<');
            console.log(element);
            return element;
        });
```

No veo el por que no filtra, si `hay match` en este if debería filtrar.  ¿ no ? ¿ que hago mal ?

Lo que no entiendo es: El console log de dentro del if **sí que me tira el filtrado**

```
// este
console.log('log -> ', element[1].filter(cosa => cosa.data !== nota.data));
// esto me tira el filtrado que quiero, correctamente
```

Pero luego el console log de fuera me sigue mostrando todos los elementos (sin el filtrado)

```
//este
console.log('>>>><<<<<');
console.log(element);
```

¿ Que hago mal ?
Me estoy quedando ciego.  XD

El `element` de allí dentro, que veis un `element[0]` y un `element[1]` eso es por que (si no se entiende) los datos existentes son algo así:

```
// element es algo como así:

[['elemento1', ["a", "b", "c"]], 'elemento2', ["a", "b", "c"]]

// Claro, yo quiero filtrar el array de dentro del array (los "a", "b", "c")
```

La idea es, una vez conseguido el filtrado, hacer el dispatch() de redux con los nuevos datos.. claro..

Gracias a quien vea el error.

Comment: Hola ferter3006. Puedes comprobar que cada element sea un array (isArray()), y si lo es, aplicar el filtro. Tienes un array con arrays anidados, por lo que deberías comprobarlo más en profundidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la ayuda de la respusta de [Sergio Yael A.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/194646/sergio-yael-a) he modificado su propuesta (100% vàlida). Para lograr una version **más elegante** ( a mi modo de entender). És esta: (por si alguien se encuentra con este problema en un futuro)

```
        const nuevasNotas = appState.notas.map(element => {
            if (element[0] === nota.data.split('T')[0]) {                
                element = [...element]
                element[1] = element[1].filter(cosa => cosa.data !== nota.data)                
            }
            return element;
        });
```

És curioso pero la línea `element = [...element]` es determinante para que funcione. (crear esta copia del array, aunque sea copiarla encima de sí mismo)

Answer (score 2):

El problema puede que se deba a que estás modificando el estado original de appState al asignar un nuevo array a la propiedad `element[1]`, pero despues lo  devuelves sin modificar en `nuevasNotas`.

Para eso deberías crear una copia del objeto y modificar la copia en lugar del objeto original.

```
const nuevasNotas = appState.notas.map(element => {
    if (element[0] === nota.data.split('T')[0]) {
        console.log('hay match!');
        const newElement = [...element]; // crea una copia del elemento actual
        newElement[1] = element[1].filter(cosa => cosa.data !== nota.data);
        console.log('log -> ', newElement[1]);
        return newElement;
    }
    console.log('>>>><<<<<');
    console.log(element);
    return element;
});
```

Creando una copia usando el operador `spread [...element]`, aseguramos que no se modifique el estado original de **appState**. Luego, podemos modificar la copia en newElement sin afectar el original.

Comment: Gracias, no puedo decir que no me guste la solución!.Aunque no suelo ser muy amigo de copiar para modificar (por el uso de memòria). Al final, ayer habia llegado a esta solución: `element = [element[0], element[1].filter(cosa=> cosa.data !== nota.data);`  Eso me estaba funcionando perfectamente, pero no me dejaba satisfecho por si un dia este array pasa a tener otro elemento en su posicion [2] (ahora vacío) <- Si un dia hay otro elemento (por modificación de la BD) se perdedería este elemento por el camino.(No con esta funcion borrar, pero sí con la de modificar que será mismo procedimiento)